# Scala upper bounds

Tags: scala, type-bounds, upperbound

In a typical Scala upperbound example

```
abstract class Animal {
  def name: String
}

abstract class Pet extends Animal {}

class Cat extends Pet {
  override def name: String = "Cat"
}

class Dog extends Pet {
  override def name: String = "Dog"
}

class Lion extends Animal {
  override def name: String = "Lion"
}
```

What is the difference between this

```
class PetContainer[P <: Pet](p: P) {
      def pet: P = p
    }

val dogContainer = new PetContainer[Dog](new Dog)
val catContainer = new PetContainer[Cat](new Cat)
```

and this?

```
class PetContainer1(p: Pet) {
      def pet: Pet = p
    }

val dogContainer1 = new PetContainer1(new Dog)
val catContainer1 = new PetContainer1(new Cat)
```

What is the advantage of using an upper type bound vs using the abstract class/trait directly?

Comment: Try adding a cat to a dog container in both examples.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With upper bound you can have a collection of specific subtype - so limiting to only cats or dogs and you can get a specific subtype back from `def pet`. It's not true for `PetContainer1`.

Losing more accurate type info example:

```
val doggo: Dog = new Dog
val dogContainer1 = new PetContainer1(doggo)
// the following won't compile
// val getDoggoBack: Dog = dogContainer1.pet  

val dogContainer2 = new PetContainer[Dog](doggo)
// that works
val getDoggoBack: Dog = dogContainer2.pet
```

You can't put a cat into dog container:

```
// this will not compile
new PetContainer[Dog](new Cat)
```

It would get more significant if you would be dealing with collections of multiple elements.

Comment: Can you plese share an example

Comment: From your example, lets say you want to get a `Dog` out of a pet container (`pc`, we'll call it).  If it's a `PetContainer[Dog]`: `val dog: Dog = pc.pet`.  If it's a `PetContainer1`, all that we know it is that it's a `Pet`, so you'd need something like (typically would be expressed as a pattern match, but the if/isInstanceOf/asInstanceOf works better in an SO comment): `val pet: Pet = pc.pet; val dog: Dog = if (pet.isInstanceOf[Dog]) pet.asInstanceOf[Dog] else ???`

Answer (score 2):

The main difference between the two is actually the difference between these two types:

```scala
def pet: P = p
// and 
def pet: Pet = p
```

So, in the first example, the type of `pet` is `P`, and in the second example, the type of `pet` is `Pet`. In other words: in the first example, the type is *more precise*, since it is a specific subtype of `Pet`.

If I put a `Dog` in the `PetContainer[Dog]`, I get a `Dog` back out. Whereas, if I put a `Dog` in the `PetContainer1`, I get back a `Pet`, which could be either a `Cat` or a `Dog`, or something else entirely. (You haven't made your classes `sealed` or `final`, so someone else could come along, and create their own subclass of `Pet`.)

If you use an editor or IDE which shows you the types of expressions, or you try your code in the REPL or in Scastie, you actually see the difference:

```scala
dogContainer.pet  // has type `Dog`
catContainer.pet  // has type `Cat`
dogContainer1.pet // has type `Pet`
catContainer1.pet // has type `Pet`
```

See [Scastie link](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/JoergWMittag/5mkNOHchSqOs6g2WJsIgpg/6) for an example:

```scala
sealed trait Animal: 
  val name: String

sealed trait Pet extends Animal

case object Cat extends Pet:
  override val name = "Cat"

case object Dog extends Pet:
  override val name = "Dog"

case object Lion extends Animal:
  override val name = "Lion"

final case class PetContainer[+P <: Pet](pet: P)

val dogContainer = PetContainer(Dog)
val catContainer = PetContainer(Cat)

final case class PetContainer1(pet: Pet)

val dogContainer1 = PetContainer1(Dog)
val catContainer1 = PetContainer1(Cat)

dogContainer.pet  //=> Dog: Dog
catContainer.pet  //=> Cat: Cat
dogContainer1.pet //=> Dog: Pet
catContainer1.pet //=> Cat: Pet
```

This gets more interesting if, say, you have a kennel that can hold two pets:

```scala
sealed trait Pet:
  val name: String

case object Cat extends Pet:
  override val name = "Cat"

case object Mouse extends Pet:
  override val name = "Mouse"

final case class UnsafePetKennel(pet1: Pet, pet2: Pet)

val unsafeCatKennel       = UnsafePetKennel(Cat, Cat)
val unsafeMouseKennel     = UnsafePetKennel(Mouse, Mouse)
val oopsSomeoneAteMyMouse = UnsafePetKennel(Cat, Mouse)

final case class SafePetKennel[+P <: Pet](pet1: P, pet2: P)

val safeCatKennel   = SafePetKennel[Cat.type](Cat, Cat)
val safeMouseKennel = SafePetKennel[Mouse.type](Mouse, Mouse)
val mouseIsSafe     = SafePetKennel[Cat.type](Cat, Mouse)
// Type error: found `Mouse`, required `Cat`
val mouseStillSafe  = SafePetKennel[Mouse.type](Cat, Mouse)
// Type error: found `Cat`, required `Mouse`
```

[Scastie link](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/JoergWMittag/mKcR9cYSROS4yJkojbo37A/9)

Unfortunately, things can still go wrong if we rely on Scala's type parameter inference:

```scala
val inferredKennel = SafePetKennel(Cat, Mouse)
```

works, because Scala infers `P` to be the least upper bound of `Cat` and `Mouse`, which is `Pet`, and thus `inferredKennel` has type `SafePetKennel[Pet]`, and since both `Cat` and `Mouse` are subtypes of `Pet`, this is allowed.

We can fix that with a slight modification to our `SafePetKennel`:

```scala
final case class SaferKennel[+P <: Pet, +Q <: Pet](
  pet1: P, pet2: Q)(implicit ev: P =:= Q)

val inferredKennel = SaferKennel(Cat, Mouse)
// Cannot prove that Cat =:= Mouse.
```

[Scastie link](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/JoergWMittag/pjwagT1RRLWBJrdyyCRD5w/8)